# Rotating sequential numbers to right

Tags: java, rotation

Its easy enough to rotate numbers to the left. I would do the following:

```
int numberCount = 4;
int rotationCount = 2 * numberCount;
for(int i = 0; i < rotationCount; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < numberCount; j++)
  {
    System.out.print((i+j) % numberCount + " ");
  }

  System.out.println();
}
```

In this example the following would be printed:

> 0 1 2 3
>
> 1 2 3 0
>
> 2 3 0 1
>
> 3 0 1 2
>
> 0 1 2 3
>
> 1 2 3 0
>
> 2 3 0 1
>
> 3 0 1 2

How would you do the same thing, but rotating the numbers to the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was obvious once I thought about it-- to move a number left, you add to it, so to move right, you subtract from it. I thought the formula would be significantly changed, so I was thinking of formulas that were much more complicated than the solution turned out to be.

```
// ensures mod is positive
int mod(int a, int b)
{ return (a%b+b)%b; }

int numberCount = 4;
int rotationCount = 2 * numberCount;

for(int i = 0; i < rotationCount; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < numberCount; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(mod((j-i), numberCount) + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```